# Hello World C++ error - cmath

Tags: c++

I am a complete beginner to C++. I am using microsoft visual studio 2015 with fltk 1.3.x and am following "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup. The current program I am working on is Hello World, the drill on p52-54.

The code I have written(/copied from the book and a supporting doc for std_lib_facilities.h [www.stroustrup.com/Programming/include-std_lib_facilities.doc]) is:

```
//My first hello world program
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()  //C++ programs start by executing the function main
{
    cout << "Hello, World!/n";  //output "Hello, world!"
    keep_window_open();         //wait for a character to be entered
    return 0;
}
```

Then I go Build -> Compile and this happens...

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)      the global scope has no "acosf" Hello_World c:\Program      Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   670
Error (active)      the global scope has no "asinf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    670
Error (active)      the global scope has no "atanf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    671
Error (active)      the global scope has no "atan2f"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    671
Error (active)      the global scope has no "ceilf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    671
Error (active)      the global scope has no "cosf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    672
Error (active)      the global scope has no "coshf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    672
Error (active)      the global scope has no "expf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    672
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fabsf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    673
Error (active)      the global scope has no "floorf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    673
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fmodf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    673
Error (active)      the global scope has no "frexpf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    674
Error (active)      the global scope has no "ldexpf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    674
Error (active)      the global scope has no "logf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    674
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log10f"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    675
Error (active)      the global scope has no "modff" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    675
Error (active)      the global scope has no "powf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    675
Error (active)      the global scope has no "sinf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    676
Error (active)      the global scope has no "sinhf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    676
Error (active)      the global scope has no "sqrtf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    676
Error (active)      the global scope has no "tanf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    677
Error (active)      the global scope has no "tanhf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    677
Error (active)      the global scope has no "acosl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    679
Error (active)      the global scope has no "asinl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    679
Error (active)      the global scope has no "atanl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    680
Error (active)      the global scope has no "atan2l"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    680
Error (active)      the global scope has no "ceill" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    680
Error (active)      the global scope has no "cosl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    681
Error (active)      the global scope has no "coshl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    681
Error (active)      the global scope has no "expl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    681
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fabsl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    682
Error (active)      the global scope has no "floorl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    682
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fmodl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    682
Error (active)      the global scope has no "frexpl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    683
Error (active)      the global scope has no "ldexpl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    683
Error (active)      the global scope has no "logl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    683
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log10l"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    684
Error (active)      the global scope has no "modfl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    684
Error (active)      the global scope has no "powl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    684
Error (active)      the global scope has no "sinl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    685
Error (active)      the global scope has no "sinhl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    685
Error (active)      the global scope has no "sqrtl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    685
Error (active)      the global scope has no "tanl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    686
Error (active)      the global scope has no "tanhl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    686
Error (active)      the global scope has no "float_t"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    688
Error (active)      the global scope has no "double_t"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    688
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nan"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    700
Error (active)      the global scope has no "acoshf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    704
Error (active)      the global scope has no "asinhf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    704
Error (active)      the global scope has no "atanhf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    704
Error (active)      the global scope has no "cbrtf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    705
Error (active)      the global scope has no "erff"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    705
Error (active)      the global scope has no "erfcf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    705
Error (active)      the global scope has no "expm1f"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    706
Error (active)      the global scope has no "exp2f" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    706
Error (active)      the global scope has no "hypotf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    707
Error (active)      the global scope has no "ilogbf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    707
Error (active)      the global scope has no "lgammaf"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    707
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log1pf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    708
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log2f" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    708
Error (active)      the global scope has no "logbf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    708
Error (active)      the global scope has no "llrintf"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    709
Error (active)      the global scope has no "lrintf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    709
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nearbyintf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    709
Error (active)      the global scope has no "rintf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    710
Error (active)      the global scope has no "llroundf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    710
Error (active)      the global scope has no "lroundf"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    710
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fdimf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    711
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fmaf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    711
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fmaxf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    711
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fminf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    711
Error (active)      the global scope has no "roundf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    712
Error (active)      the global scope has no "truncf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    712
Error (active)      the global scope has no "remainderf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    713
Error (active)      the global scope has no "remquof"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    713
Error (active)      the global scope has no "copysignf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    714
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nanf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    714
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nextafterf"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    715
Error (active)      the global scope has no "scalbnf"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    715
Error (active)      the global scope has no "scalblnf"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    715
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nexttowardf"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    716
Error (active)      the global scope has no "tgammaf"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    716
Error (active)      the global scope has no "acoshl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    718
Error (active)      the global scope has no "asinhl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    718
Error (active)      the global scope has no "atanhl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    718
Error (active)      the global scope has no "cbrtl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    719
Error (active)      the global scope has no "erfl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    719
Error (active)      the global scope has no "erfcl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    719
Error (active)      the global scope has no "expm1l"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    720
Error (active)      the global scope has no "exp2l" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    720
Error (active)      the global scope has no "hypotl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    721
Error (active)      the global scope has no "ilogbl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    721
Error (active)      the global scope has no "lgammal"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    721
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log1pl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    722
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log2l" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    722
Error (active)      the global scope has no "logbl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    722
Error (active)      the global scope has no "llrintl"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    723
Error (active)      the global scope has no "lrintl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    723
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nearbyintl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    723
Error (active)      the global scope has no "rintl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    724
Error (active)      the global scope has no "llroundl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    724
Error (active)      the global scope has no "lroundl"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    724
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fdiml" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    725
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fmal"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    725
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fmaxl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    725
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fminl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    725
Error (active)      the global scope has no "roundl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    726
Error (active)      the global scope has no "truncl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    726
Error (active)      the global scope has no "remainderl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    727
Error (active)      the global scope has no "remquol"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    727
Error (active)      the global scope has no "copysignl" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    728
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nanl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    728
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nextafterl"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    729
Error (active)      the global scope has no "scalbnl"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    729
Error (active)      the global scope has no "scalblnl"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    729
Error (active)      the global scope has no "nexttowardl"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    730
Error (active)      the global scope has no "tgammal"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    730
Error (active)      the global scope has no "fpclassify"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    732
Error (active)      the global scope has no "signbit"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    732
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isfinite"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    733
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isinf" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    733
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isnan" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    734
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isnormal"  Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    734
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isgreater" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    735
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isgreaterequal"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    735
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isless"    Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    736
Error (active)      the global scope has no "islessequal"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    736
Error (active)      the global scope has no "islessgreater" Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    737
Error (active)      the global scope has no "isunordered"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath    737
Error (active)      cannot open source file "/usr/include/math.h"   Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\math.h   22
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: '/usr/include/math.h': No such file or directory  Hello_World c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h   22
Error (active)      linkage specification is incompatible with previous "copysign" (declared at line 53 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\math.h") Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h    183
Error (active)      linkage specification is incompatible with previous "rint"     (declared at line 52 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     14.0\VC\include\math.h") Hello_World c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual     Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h    207
```

I am thinking that this relates to the std_lib_facilities.h file. The book recommends use of fltk 1.1.x and visual studio 2005 so maybe this is also part of the problem?

Any insight you can give is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just tried using the `std_lib_facilities.h` in VS2015 (w/o fltk) and the example works.

Comment: `cout << "Hello, World!/n";` wil output "Hello, world!/n", not "Hello, world!" with a new line

Comment: You are correct, thank you. The book has 
    cout << "Hello, World!\n"; i.e. / change to \. This does not change the errors though.

Comment: 2 things that look suspicious. 1.)  I don't have a file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\math.h" and there is no include to this in any of my files. 2.) `cannot open source file "/usr/include/math.h"` should not appear on Windows.

|| Can you explan this?

Comment: @Simon
1) I deleted the math.h file, went Build -> clean solution, then Build -> compile. 
'The output was 1>------ Build started: Project: Hello_World, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------  
    1>  Hello_World.cpp  
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========='
Does this mean that the problem is solved?

Comment: Looks good. Try to run the program.

Comment: @user5267538 Does it start? Do you have any idea where that math.h came from?

Comment: Sorry. Compiling the reply. 
Debug -> Start without debug
The project is out of date: Hello_World - Debug Win32. Would you like to build it?
Yes.
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib' Hello_World c:\Users\Benjamin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Hello_World\Hello_World\LINK 1
//'fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib' was what the book told to put into Hello_World property pages -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Comment: There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?
1. Yes
 Unable to start program 'c:\users\benjamin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Hello_World\Debug\Hello_World.exe'.
Then comes up with 132 errors. They look very similar (probably the same) to the ones in the original post.
2. No
Comes up with the 132 errors straight away.

Comment: @user5267538 I think your dependencies are not set up correctly.
Why don't you just start from the scratch and try to setup a new project?

Answer (score 0):

that should work

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;   //endl = /n

    system("pause")      //system pause = wait till user entering a char

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -4):

Im pretty new too but heres how I did it using visual studio:

---

```
// my first program in c++

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

cout <<"Hello World! I am a c++ program.";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Basically all you need is to use the #include < iostream > 
That will tell the computer to use those functions in order to carry out the program (take out the spaces). 
You also need to include: using namespace std; if you want to say "cout". Otherwise you have to specify and say std before cout. 
Lastly you can just take out the "keep window open thing". You dont need that as long as you just click CTRL-F5 to run the program. 
Hope that Helped!
Goodluck!

Comment: This code won't work. use `#include <iostream>` instead of `Hashtag include < iostream >`.

Comment: No, it definitely works. And obviously youre supposed to use an actual # rather than the word.